# W.s.s. Gaussian process in LTI, probability of the output signal

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convolution, density-function, stationary-processes

Let {${X(t); t\in ℝ}$} be a wide sense stationary Gaussian process with mean $\mu_X = 1$ and power spectral density $$S_X(f) = \begin{cases} 1, \ \text{if} \ |f| < 5; \\ 0, \ \text{otherwise}.
 \end{cases}$$

This process is the input of a LTI with impulse response $$h(t) = \begin{cases} 8e^{-4t}, \ \text{if} \ t >0; \\0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Let {${Y(t); t\in ℝ}$} be the output signal.

We must compute $P(Y(1)>1)$.

As {${X(t); t\in ℝ}$} is wide sense stationary, I know that we can compute its autocorrelation function as the inverse Fourier transform of its power spectral density $S_X(f)$. This gives us : $$ R_X(\tau) = sinc \ (\frac {5} {\pi} \tau)$$

**Here is my question**, I don't know how to make the link between this autocorrelation function and the probability that we want to compute. Should I compute the convolution $$ R_X(\tau) \ \ * \ \ h(1)$$

But then I don't how to use the given mean...

Or should I use the fact that the input signal {${X(t); t\in ℝ}$} is a Gaussian process to say that the output signal also is, and somehow compute the probability using this ?

Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks.

Comment: There are many misconceptions in your question such as ignoring the nonzero mean of the input process and its effect on the power spectral density and autocorrelation function of the process.